# NFC Android app triggering-java card applet

Tags: nfc, apdu

I'm working on an NFC payment project. When the phone touches the POS with a transaction, normally the Android application can be triggered. How can an Android application be triggered? We had developed an applet to deal with communications and send APDUs to the telephone.
Something like dispatch system for tags, but I couldn't find the same mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Your POS terminal is really a Java Card? Then you want to set your NFC tech filter to catch [android.nfc.tech.ISODep](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html) intents. To my knowledge there is no way to restrict this to a specific Java Card applet AID: your app will be launched for all ISO 14443 cards in the proximity of your phone.

Comment: i mean, during the process of transaction, the pos will firstly communicate with sim card, then the android app,android.nfc.tech.ISODep is used for tag. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of smart card to process the APDUs. As far as I know there is no current API to process APDUs in an Android application. The reason is that the Android OS does not provide sufficient security for applications such as banks. Google uses an embedded smart card to run the Google Wallet, mobile operators offer the same in the SIM.

Once you have access to a smartcard (by the way Google will never let you install anything on theirs), you must write a javacard application to load it there. You best bet would be an NFC enabled phone, with card emulation directed to the SIM, and a test SIM to try out.

Then, from your javacard application you can trigger an Android application to display some nice GUI.

Comment: thank you very much your answer,do u konw how can an javacard applet trigger the android app?

Comment: Depends on the secure element. On the embedded SE you need your app to be registered on the AID_SELECTED intent. On UICC the application needs to use the ETSI 102 705 API. Then, depending on the handset this will be reflected in upper layers as TRANSACTION_DETECTED intent. Check Android source code, GSMA and AFSCM specifications.